# Decimal columns in SQL Server Table not displaying correct value when inserting element from AngularJS HTTP service

Tags: c#, sql, json, angularjs, decimal

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app that runs on .NET Framework 4.5.2. I'm trying to insert a record into a table on my `SQL Server` database. I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3 for this and `AngularJS` to make an HTTP request to my server. When inserting into the table, the `text` and `varchar` columns are working perfectly, but all the `decimal` columns have `0` as value.

I checked to see if the data that I'm passing to the HTTP request is correct, and it is. I noticed that if I change the column type from `decimal` to `string` on my `Entity Data Model` the value is no longer `0`, but as expected that doesn't work because the data types on the Model don't match the data types on my database.

Then I looked at the values that I'm passing to the `Entity Data Model` to see if that was the issue. They had this format: `123,456.78`. I tried swapping the dots and commas to see if that would make any change: `123.456,78`, but that didn't work either.

I also noticed the `date` columns are not inserted properly either. On the database they are inserted like this: `/Date(-62135596800000)/` and they always have the same value `0001-01-01`. But that doesn't bother me at all because I can change their type to `varchar`.

This is my `HTTP request`:

```
$http({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        datatype: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.data)
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

And this is my `Insert` method:

```
   public string Insert_Record(Purchase_Orders r)
    {
        if (r != null)
        {
            using (Purchase_OrdersEntities obj = new Purchase_OrdersEntities())
            {
                //checking the value of one of the decimal columns
                Debug.WriteLine(r.Invoiced);

                obj.Purchase_Orders.Add(r);
                obj.SaveChanges();

                return "Record inserted successfully";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Record not inserted.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `123,456.78` is a formatted value, not a decimal literal. Remove the comma instead of swapping commas and dots.

Comment: just a thought, what are the values getting framed to model just before save is called? if its good then also check are those values are correctly in format w.r.t the table schema? Inspecting the data just before save and cross checking it with table schema might help you to narrow down more.

Comment: @SalmanA Yeah, that was it. I also had to use a comma for the decimal separator, I feel ashamed that I didn't think of that lol. Thank you!